# Why my orginal list is getting same values as my duplicate list while list.removeall()

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, lambda

```
listRemoveMarkers = listCurrentPostsMarkers;

listRemoveMarkers.RemoveAll(x =>
  listLocations.Exists(y => y.Latitude == x.Position.Latitude && 
                            y.Longitude == x.Position.Longitude));
```

While Debugging Line by Line - **listCurrentPostsMarkers** has 2 values then assigning the same values in the other list "**listRemoveMarkers**" and removing all values from **listRemoveMarkers** after comparing with **listLocations** list. RemoveAll() is working fine and I got the required values in the **listRemoveMarkers** But now I don't know why my **listCurrentPostsMarkers** is getting affected? It gets the same values as **listRemoveMarkers**. Help me to understand this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have two lists. You have two *variables* that both contain *references* to the *same* list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
listRemoveMarkers = listCurrentPostsMarkers;
```

Does not create a new list but makes the `listRemoveMarkers` reference point to the same instance.

You can create a new list to avoid this:

```
listRemoveMarkers = listCurrentPostsMarkers.Where(x =>
  !listLocations.Exists(y => y.Latitude == x.Position.Latitude 
                          && y.Longitude == x.Position.Longitude)).
  ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I did "listRemoveMarkers = listCurrentPostsMarkers.ToList();"

Comment: @fineline OK,`RemoveAll` is a bit redundant since framework 3.5 and Linq

Comment: Ok, Then what would be the appropriate option to do the same?

Comment: @fineline 'appropriate' is a matter of personal opinion but I'd use the code I posted